# Why the bson java implementation uses 4 bytes inc field?

Tags: java, mongodb, driver, bson, objectid

In BSON Java implementation, an ObjectId is composed by 3 pieces (source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.9.0/org/bson/types/ObjectId.java#ObjectId.%3Cinit%3E%28int%2Cint%2Cint%29 ):

```
XXXX   XXXX          XXXX
-------------------------
time   machine&pid   inc
```

*(each X represents a byte)*

this is a bit different from what's described in document (doc: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/object-id/ )

```
XXXX   XXX       XX    XXX
--------------------------
time   machine   pid   inc
```

*(each X represents a byte)*

Can anyone let me know **why the java-driver didn't follow the spec?**

Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, Java's approach is better, because it gives 8 bits more randomness (since inc is initialized randomly).  The "machine/pid" thing does nothing but significantly increase the chances of a collision in a large cluster compared to simply using 12 bytes of randomness.

Answer (score 1):

I will put this as answer since it is a bit long for a comment.

There are a couple of JIRA links to this:

- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-81
- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-337

The second acknowledges that the spec is different under Java however makes no reference as to why.

If I were to make a guess it could be due to the way the PID and machine id in Java works, it could be related to: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-586.

You may find your answer better on the Google Group: mongodb-user since the maintainers hang out there.

Comment: Thanks Sammaye, according to the JIRAs, it seems to be a known issue. I'm not able to access google group from China, would you please help me forward my question to the group? btw, my real question is [Hack ObjectId to indicate the object type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769013/hack-objectid-to-indicate-the-object-type), can you please add some comments? Thanks~~~

Comment: I have forwarded it, hopefully there will be a response soon, I'll take a look at that other one but kristina does have the right idea.

Comment: There are historical reasons for the difference, but JAVA-337 is currently planned to be addressed in the 3.0 Java driver release (i.e. the ObjectIDs will conform to the spec).

Comment: @Stennie Can you the reason be stated? That is basically this question.

Comment: @Stennie Oh never mind it seems the JIRA has been updated talking about machine id

Comment: "Historical" means that's the way ObjectIDs have been generated in the Java driver and there are existing users relying on that implementation ;-).  If you look at the [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) you will see there are a few subtypes for UUID used by older drivers.  In order to introduce the "correct" ObjectID spec to the Java driver there will likely have to be some support for the "Java legacy" ObjectID.  I expect the original intent of an ObjectID was to provide a reasonably unique primary key, rather than packing fields that drivers would then start parsing as data.

Comment: @Stennie aha awesome cheers, you should put that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I expect the original intent of an ObjectID was to generate a reasonably unique primary key, rather than packing fields that drivers would then start parsing as data.

As the MongoDB ecosystem has evolved, some developers have found it useful to interpret the ObjectID from multiple drivers as well as ensure consistency of generated IDs.

If you look at the [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) you will see there are a few subtypes for UUID used by older drivers, and various changes for interoperability.  For example, there is mention on [PYTHON-387](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-387) of supporting "legacy" byte orders and endianness for the C# and Java drivers.

As per [JAVA-337](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-337) in the MongoDB issue tracker, the Java driver's ObjectID inconsistency is planned to be addressed in the 3.0 Java driver release.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why they are different, but I can tell you that the Python driver generates object ids using the same approach that the Java one does:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/bson/objectid.py